# org-metaup/down deletes line instead of swapping it up/down

Tags: org-mode

I am using emacs 24.5.1 and do not understand how to shift outlines up/down in org-mode

Let's say I have the following list:

```
* Title 1
** section a
** section b
** section c
```

I would like to swap sections b and c. According to the manual this is achieved by using the keys M-up/down for items or M-S-up/down for subtree items. If I try M-down on "section b" for instance, I expect the following:

```
* Title 1
** section a
** section c
** section b
```

But instead I get:

```
* Title 1
** section a
** section c
```

The command deletes the current line ! It seems to work only with tickbox lists...

I checked my key-bindings with C-h k and they are calling the right commands. They are also displayed properly in the org-mode menu. I also tried to execute the commands

```
(org-shiftmetadown)
(org-move-subtree-down)
(org-move-item-down)
```

directly in the minibuffer but always get the same behaviour (line is deleted). I thought about a conflict with cua-mode but disabling it does not help.

I am missing something ? How to move outline items up/dow in org-mode ?

Answer (score 0):

It shows M-up is bounded to command org-metaup in my case. And it moves subtree or table row up depending the context. Could you please try the command org-metaup and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks, org-metaup does the same as the other commands, it deletes the current line...